# How can I replace "o" in "Hello world" with another variable and "d" of the "...world"

Tags: assembly, masm32

```
String: db "Hello World"
nonhuman: db 0
move SI,String+4
move ax,[SI]
move [nonhuman],ax
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what you're asking. In what you've shown replace AX with AL because otherwise the MOVE SI,... will get overwritten!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like homework, so no straight answer.

You store bytes in memory using the MOV command. One argument can be a constant, the other has to be a regiater. You can use addressing with displacement, as in [SI + 4]. Bytelong registers are AL/AH, BL/BH and so on. AX, BX and such are two bytes long.

To load a byte from memory you also use MOV, but the memory location needs to be the second operand, not the first one.

With this in mind, the code goes:

```
load the replacement value from memory into a byte-sized register
store that register in the string+4 (the position of O)
store that same register in the string+10 (the position of D)
```

That is, unless your task is replacing o's and d's in an arbitrary string, not just in this one. In that case, you need a loop, you need to read the byte from the string and compare it, and replace conditionally.